Must a domain of discourse always be specified in universally quantified statements?
Some logic texts formulate universally quantified statements without specifying a domain of discourse D.
For example
For any x: x isn't alive.
They take it for granted that x ∈ U, where it's true that
∀ x[x ∈ U]
My question is, do you always need to specify the domain of discourse, OR when it's unstated is it U by default?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

A simple response is to say that you don't need to specify the domain of discourse because often it is possible to do logic just by pushing the symbols around and without saying what the symbols mean. We can write down some formulas and show that this formula is derivable from those formulas, without providing an interpretation. It is only when we ask what the formulas mean and whether they are true that the interpretation matters.
Your use of the symbol U is unclear. Many texts use U to denote a structure that specifies a domain |U| which is the universe of U, a function that maps the constant symbols in the language to the distinguished elements of U, a function that maps the predicate symbols in the language to tuples defined over the elements of U, and a function that maps the function symbols in the language to functions defined over the elements of U. (See for example, Enderton, A Mathematical Introduction to Logic, 2nd ed, Chapter 2, pp. 80-81; or Hinman, Fundamentals of Mathematical Logic, Chapter 2, pp. 90-91.)
U is not a universal set in any sense supplied by an outside theory. It is just a structure chosen for some purpose. Many textbooks describe the domain as a set, but we shouldn't read too much into that. Logic can be thought of as fundamental and so logic does not depend on set theory. It is better to think of the domain as an informal collection or plurality of things that serves to specify what the variables in a formula range over. Peter Smith expresses the same thought like this: "For convenience we can think of this domain, the objects the quantifiers of a language run over, as forming a set: but don't over-interpret the lightweight set talk here." (Introduction to Formal Logic, 2nd ed, section 27.3, p. 252.)
Usually, in a formal piece of work, the writer will specify the domain that it is concerned with. But in ordinary language, the domain may just be implied by the context. If someone says, "All the beer is in the fridge," we understand that they are not talking about all the beer in the universe. The important thing about a domain is that it must remain constant within the scope of a particular piece of work.

my use of U comes from an outside use of set theory.  But so far as FOL is concerned, it's constants are undesignated, and therefore uninterrupted..  a constant like 'Socrates'' is not part of FOL, because it has a meaning.   To be more clear about my use of U, predicates and individuals are elements of the set.  But the constants of FOL, whose intended interpretation is individuals or predicates, remain uninterrupted symbols of the language.

Change uninterrupted to uninterpreted.

+1 In type theory, U is used in an arbitrary and similar way as Bumble describes, and it is not impossible simply to have one U contain a distinct U. Consider, for instance, Coquand's article in the SEP that says "One such extension of Church’s simple type theory is obtained by adding universes (Martin-Löf 1970). Adding a universe is a reflection process: we add a type U whose objects are the types considered so far." "Types considered so far" makes it indefinitely extensible, a fact reiterated by Friedman and Christiansen's The Little Typer. Using U is an ad hoc and voluntary decision.

And that would be one hell of a fridge

In principle, no, U is not necessarily the default. It may appear to be that way given it is the most common of the domains, but(especially when regarding non-philosophical texts) other domains may be the logical default without specification. That being said, it is generally perceived as a lapse in rigor and unnecessary ambiguity to not specify. So for the most part you will find that authors take the time to note their intended domain.

+1 "In principle, U is not necessary" it is enough. U will be different for different interpretations: thus, to add x ∈ U is simply useless :-) BUT, if - as the OP seems to assert - U is some sort of "universal set" that is fixed irrespective of the interpretation, that is simply wrong.

There is no set "U" of which to talk about unless it is a set theory...

@Mauro, U as I understand it, is the name of the set of all things.  In FOL, you postulate an unlimited number of individual constants, say x1,x2,x3,x4,... They are intended to refer to individuals, when interpreted.  So that intension involves the understanding that there is a set of all individuals.  The meaning of U is fixed, prior to the actual assignment of meanings.  What I am saying is, whatever the symbols x1,x2,x3,...are intended to represent, the referents MUST BE elements of U.

@Mairo, I mean them to be the specific constants of the language.  For example, you can use Existential Instantiation in a proof as follows:  There exists an x, such that P(x); therefore P(xi), for some specific constant xi.  I don't intend for names of the elements of U to be variables of FOL.

@Mauro, In my musings about FOL, I maintain the postulate that every individual has at least one name.   Therefore the constants cannot all refer to the same individual.

The answer is surely "it depends".  In some contexts, you do have to specify the domain of discourse, such as when applying the transfer principle of nonstandard analysis.  Here one cannot quantify over unbound variables; attempting to do so will produce incorrect statements.  More specifically, quantification in a formula must take the form (forall x in A) etc., which will then be transferred to (forall x in A*) etc. (and similarly for the existence quantifier, of course).  Free variables can occur as parameters in a formula (without quantification).

Well, for the sake of discussion, this answer too is wrong: you guys might have in mind restricted comprehension and the need for "bounded quantification", which is a requirement of (the usual) set theory, but there is no such logical requirement, indeed fundamentally "forall x in T, P" is shorthand for "forall x, x in T -> P".

You are simply pointing out that the notation x in T is abbreviated notation for the longer formula you mentioned.  This is certainly do, but is irrelevant to the point made in my answer.

@julio, you are completely right about that.  It is just a shorthand.

(1/2) @MikhailKatz  It is not irrelevant: to recap, I am 1) objecting (not just to you) to the fact that the answer depends on context, there is a technical definition of "universe of discourse"; 2) specifically pointing out that the basic quantification element is "forall x", not "forall x in T", which is relevant to the question of what and where is "the universe of discourse (in logic)"; and

(2/2)  3) what you bring up is in fact relevant to set theory, restricted comprehension essentially ("one cannot quantify over unbound variables"). but again, what is in question here is not a notion of set theory, we are talking of logic as in the underlying logical language (and its theory), e.g. FOL: and there is no such requirement in logic.

Consider the following:
Translate All American persons have the right to a lawyer

Not delimiting the domain
∀x((Px ∧ Ax) → Lx) = For all x, if x is a person AND x is American then, x has the right to a lawyer.

Delimiting the domain
Domain = American persons
∀x(Lx) =  For all x, x has the right to a lawyer. x can only be an American person.


Fixing the domain simplifies the corresponding logical statements.

This answer too is wrong, the domain of discourse is not a restriction by a predicate: "In the formal sciences, the domain of discourse, also called the universe of discourse, universal set, or simply universe, is the set of entities over which certain variables of interest in some formal treatment may range" (Wikipedia), though that is for an informal notion of "set", indeed it's quite badly phrased, it's not set theory and that is at the meta level, but I have no better reference right now.

@JulioDiEgidio I think you may be misunderstanding this answer. As I read it, Hudjefa is not saying that the domain is a predicate restriction. The answer is saying that 2 can be used to express the same proposition as 1 if we consider "American persons" to be the universe of discourse. "American persons" may be described informally as a collection of things that the variable x ranges over, without commitment to any formal account of set theory.

Regardless of 1 and 2, "fixing the domain of discourse" in that sense is simply not it (IMO): i.e. that is simply not what "universe of discourse" means technically, which has to do with the range of variables, not with the range of "the discourse".  -- And I was tempted to post my own answer to the question (so that you can also criticise it :)), but I am not doing it because I think the question, as is, is not good enough, and it is not conducive to good answers: I have voted to close it...
